# Setting mouse cursor in pyglet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm trying to set the mouse cursor in a pyglet application. According to the pyglet documentation, this is how I should go about this:

```py
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

cursor = window.get_system_mouse_cursor(win.CURSOR_HELP)
window.set_mouse_cursor(cursor)

pyglet.app.run()
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
cursor = window.get_system_mouse_cursor(win.CURSOR_HELP)
NameError: name 'win' is not defined
```

How can I do this without using my own cursor image files? I'm on linux if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CURSOR_HELP attribute is a member of your window class.

Change

```py
win.CURSOR_HELP
```

to

```py
window.CURSOR_HELP
```

Found here: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/window/pyglet.window.Window.html#pyglet.window.Window.CURSOR_HELP